# AngularJS - table from ng-repeat on one-level array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-table

I have an array with `N` elements:

```
$scope.arr = ["1","2","3" ... ,"N"]
```

I need to make from it a **table** with `X` columns and `N/X` rows.

Can I use `ng-repeat` to achieve it?

I know that I can manipulate the array to this format :
  `$scope.arr = [["1","2","3"], ["4","5","6"] ...]`  and then I can use nested ng-repeat.

But I want to know if **it possible** to do it one *one-level array*.

Comment: and where is definition for X

Comment: Let say  $scope.X =5, What is the diffrent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.x = 3;

  $scope.arr = [];

  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    $scope.arr.push(i)
  }

  $scope.getColumns = function() {

    return new Array($scope.x)

  }

  $scope.getRows = function() {

    return new Array(Math.ceil(($scope.arr.length) / $scope.x))

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    Columns:
    <input type="number" ng-model="x" />

    <table border="1">
      <tr ng-repeat="i in getRows() track by $index" ng-init="idx = $index">
        <td ng-repeat="c in getColumns() track by $index" ng-init="idy=$index">{{arr[(idx*x)+idy]}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Nice problem. This is what I came up with:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZBrJB/43/

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Main">
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="r in rows()">
        <td ng-repeat="c in columns(r)">{{ c }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('Main', function($scope){

    $scope.arr = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18"];

    $scope.columnCount = 2;

  $scope.rows = function(){
    var input = [];
    for (var i=0; i< $scope.arr.length / $scope.columnCount; i++) input.push(i);
    return input;
  };

  $scope.columns = function(row){
      var start = row * $scope.columnCount;
      var end = start + $scope.columnCount;
    var input = [];
    for (var i=start; i< end; i++) input.push($scope.arr[i]);
    return input;
  };
});
```

Comment: Nice, but it's possible to do it without involve the controller? only pure HTML and ng-repeat tricks?

Comment: @cheziHoyzer, hmm, that's tricky, I don't think so, but if there's anything I've learned from SO is that there is always some dude who can do it. Still, there are some calculations going on that you need the controller for and the row count needs to be available in the td repeat. So no, I don't think so. I figured that since you used "$scope.arr = []" using a controller would be fine.

Comment: Of course I need the contrller - every view need a controller. but I thought, because this is only view manipulation maybe all the logic need to be in the view, maybe I should use filter for this..